# Comando INSERT no php não está funcionando

Tags: php, postgresql

Estou passando um projeto em PHP que fiz no servidor local, para um servidor pago. Quando estava usando apenas o local da minha máquina, tudo funcionava. Porém ao passar todo o programa para o novo servidor, apareceu o problema. Estou utilizando o banco de dados PostgreSQL, e ao tentar executar um comando INSERT, para inserir os dados no BD, aparece a mensagem que foi cadastrado porém não é cadastrado no BD. Os comandos DELETE e UPDATE estão funcionando normalmente. Segue o código

```
$inserir = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO produtos values (nextval('produto_id_seq'::regclass),:nome, :preco,:tipo,  :imagem, :medida, :observacao);");
                        $inserir->bindParam(':nome', $nomeprod, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $inserir->bindParam(':preco', $preco, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $inserir->bindParam(':tipo', $tipo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $inserir->bindParam(':imagem', $novoNome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $inserir->bindParam(':medida', $medida, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $inserir->bindParam(':observacao', $observacao, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $inserir->execute();
```

Comment: Faça `if(!$inserir->execute()){ print_r($stmt->errorInfo()); }` e veja se aparece algum erro, se sim edite a pergunta e adicione ele :)

Comment: Não apareceu nem um erro colocando esta linha de código.

Comment: Se vc rodar esse insert direto no banco de produçã da erro?

Comment: Já testei um INSERT com dados prontos e ao executar no banco funcionou perfeitamente, após isso, copiei o mesmo INSERT  para testar pelo programa, e o erro continuou.

Comment: Ah,agora apareceu o erro, foi o seguinte    `Array([0] => 42501 [1] => 7[2] => ERRO : permissão negada para sequência produto_id_seq)` @rray

Comment: Eu tentaria resolver da seguinte forma primeiro, no lugar do `nextval()` mandar um `null` caso não de certo iria verificar a questão de permissão da sequence. Pelo menos agora tem um erro para corrigir :)

Comment: Coloquei o null e apareceu o seguinte `erro: valor nulo na coluna "id_produto" viola a restrição não-nula` @rray

Comment: Se vc especificar os nomes das colunas com os respectivos valores e claro não incluir o `id_produto` ?

Comment: Ao fazer isso, o erro inicial retorna. (permissão negada para sequência)

Comment: vc está usando o pgAdmin ou phpPgAdmin? consegue dar a permissão na sequence por lá?

Comment: Também pensei nisso, estava vasculhando as permissões e aparentemente só há permissão para UPDATE e SELECT, acabei de contactar o provedor para liberar a permissão. Se der certo, retorno aqui para relatar. Obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 1):

O problema era apenas no privilégio mesmo, como dito. Pedi ao provedor que liberasse para mim(Na verdade eu mesmo poderia ter liberado tal privilégio), e funcionou. Obrigado pela atenção.